# Sorting a column and setting the result to another column in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a problem about a query. Let's say I have a table structure like this.

```
TABLE_A
Id - Standing - Point
1      null       8
2      null       9
3      null       12
4      null       11
5      null       4
```

When I sort this table by Point column(SELECT * FROM TABLE_A ORDER BY Point DESC), I want to update Standing column to be updated according to sort results. After sorting and setting these values to Standing column, the result that I want to have is this:

```
TABLE_A
Id - Standing - Point
1      4        8
2      3        9
3      1        12
4      2        11
5      5        4
```

Is it possible to do this? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: As a rule, you should not store data that can be easily derived from other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the rather arcane syntax:

```
update table_A
    set standing = (select cnt
                    from (select count(*) as cnt
                          from table_a a2
                          where a2.point >= table_A.point
                         )
                   )
```

The use of the nested select is simply a syntax convention required in MySQL.